# Retriving data from tags with a certain value

Tags: javascript, autohotkey

I have been trying to get text after `<strong>` tag that has a certain value in AHK. Say I am interested in what comes after: `<strong>Author(s): </strong>`. Here's an attempt to do so. It almost does the trick but the output string starts with some white space. (There is no white space is the original string). How do I fix this?

```
IE := ComObjCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible := false
IE.Navigate("https://www.ceeol.com/search/article-detail?id=298665")

while IE.readyState != 4 || IE.document.readyState != "complete" || IE.busy
    Sleep 10

detail := IE.document.getElementsByClassName("article-detail-description")
div := detail[0].getElementsByTagName("div")
str := StrSplit(div[0].innerHTML, "<br>")

for index, val in str{
    if(InStr(val, "Author(s): ")){
        sName := StrReplace(val, "<strong>Author(s): </strong>")
        Break
    }
}

MsgBox, % sName
ExitApp
```

Comment: Can you please re-paraphrase the question? I can't understand your problem

Comment: @Qaddura I need text that is right after `<strong>Author(s): </strong>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have white-space at the start of the returned Div -- some new line plus some spaces.  Try:

```
    sName := Trim(SubStr(StrReplace(val, "<strong>Author(s): </strong>"), 2))
```

The 2 is the linefeed and first space character.  Since subsequent fields won't have that linefeed, you would change to 1:

```
if(InStr(val, "Keywords: ")){
    sName := Trim(SubStr(StrReplace(val, "<strong>Keywords: </strong>"), 1))
```

which is equivalent to what you had:

```
    sName := StrReplace(val, "<strong>Keywords: </strong>")
```

Hth,

Comment: Thanks! I will test it tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to test it and it is working as it should be! I really appreciate your answer and detailed explanation.